# Select distinct rows from multiple column query

Tags: sql-server

I have this query that currently returns all the pertinent information I need, but I need it to only return unique `DISPLAYCLAIMNUMBER` rows. I have tried throwing a `DISTINCT` before it, but that gives me an error for invalid syntax. I'm pretty confused on how to put `DISTINCT` on something that is in the middle of my `SELECT`. The order of my query is also important, because I'm sending the data to an Excel table. I'm sure this is an extremely inefficient, but the database is very fragmented, and I have to refer to several tables, just for one piece of data. Feel free to improve, if there is a way to.

```
SELECT cd.NAMECREFID, clm.CONTACTNAME, cd.ASSIGNEDPOLICY, clm.DISPLAYCLAIMNUMBER, clm.CAUSEOFLOSS, scp.PERILCODE, scp.DESCRIBE, clm.ASSIGNEDDATETIME, clm.CLOSEDATETIME, clp.PAYMENT
FROM CLMSTAT clm
inner join SCPERTBL scp on clm.ASSIGNEDPERILNUMBER = scp.PERILCODE
inner join CLMPYMT clp on clm.ASSIGNEDCLAIMNUMBER = clp.ASSIGNEDCLAIMNUMBER 
inner join SNAMES sn on clm.CONTACTNAME = sn.NAME
inner join TCUSDTL cd on sn.NAMEID = cd.NAMEID
WHERE clm.CONTACTNAME Like '%Smith%'
ORDER BY clm.CONTACTNAME, clm.ASSIGNEDDATETIME DESC
```

Comment: Is DISPLAYCLAIMNUMBER unique in CLMSTAT or are there duplicates there.  If it is unique then one of your joins are creating duplicates in the result - first step is to figure out which one and eliminate them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply try this

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT -- at the start
cd.NAMECREFID, clm.CONTACTNAME, cd.ASSIGNEDPOLICY, clm.DISPLAYCLAIMNUMBER, clm.CAUSEOFLOSS, scp.PERILCODE, scp.DESCRIBE, clm.ASSIGNEDDATETIME, clm.CLOSEDATETIME, clp.PAYMENT
FROM CLMSTAT clm
inner join SCPERTBL scp on clm.ASSIGNEDPERILNUMBER = scp.PERILCODE
inner join CLMPYMT clp on clm.ASSIGNEDCLAIMNUMBER = clp.ASSIGNEDCLAIMNUMBER 
inner join SNAMES sn on clm.CONTACTNAME = sn.NAME
inner join TCUSDTL cd on sn.NAMEID = cd.NAMEID
WHERE clm.CONTACTNAME Like '%Smith%'
ORDER BY clm.CONTACTNAME, clm.ASSIGNEDDATETIME DESC
```

This will give you a unique combination of all columns in the SELECT list.

However if this is not what you desire, and you simply want unique values for `clm.DISPLAYCLAIMNUMBER` only, I'd ask why do you need rest? If you don't then your query's SELECT list should be like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT clm.DISPLAYCLAIMNUMBER
FROM CLMSTAT clm 
...
```

Comment: I need the rest for data analysis purposes, but this seems to have done what I wanted. I was under the impression that everything would be affected by `DISTINCT`. For example, only one row per `CONTACTNAME` would display, but that's not the case, it seems. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cd.NAMECREFID, clm.CONTACTNAME, cd.ASSIGNEDPOLICY, clm.DISPLAYCLAIMNUMBER, clm.CAUSEOFLOSS, scp.PERILCODE, scp.DESCRIBE, clm.ASSIGNEDDATETIME, clm.CLOSEDATETIME, clp.PAYMENT
FROM CLMSTAT clm
inner join SCPERTBL scp on clm.ASSIGNEDPERILNUMBER = scp.PERILCODE
inner join CLMPYMT clp on clm.ASSIGNEDCLAIMNUMBER = clp.ASSIGNEDCLAIMNUMBER 
inner join SNAMES sn on clm.CONTACTNAME = sn.NAME
inner join TCUSDTL cd on sn.NAMEID = cd.NAMEID
WHERE clm.CONTACTNAME Like '%Smith%'
GROUP BY clm.DISPLAYCLAIMNUMBER
ORDER BY clm.CONTACTNAME, clm.ASSIGNEDDATETIME DESC
```

Comment: I've tried multiple variations of this. It seems to always throw a syntax error. Your exact example does as well.

Comment: To use GROUP BY you need to aggregate all fields not in the GROUP BY.